# How to prevent Windows 7 Remote Desktop time outs?

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, timeout

I can't seem to get some Windows 7 machines to prevent active but idle Remote Desktop connections from timing out.

I've changed all of the local group policy settings on my test machine under

```
Computer Configuration
 Admin Templates
  Windows Components
   Remote Desktop Session Host
    Session Time Limits
```

To disabled and I still get time outs of active but idle sessions.

Is there any where else I need to make changes?

Comment: Windows 7 is not a Remote Desktop Session Host so I don't believe those settings aren't going to have any bearing.

Comment: Is this computer part of a domain? If so have you checked the GPOs that apply to that machine/User. Also in AD there are remote settings that apply to this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Push Start > then type "Local Security Policy"

Inside the Local Secuirty Policy Snap in

> Security settings > Security Options > Microsoft Network Server: Amount of idle time required before suspending session

Default is 15 minutes.

Comment: this setting is for SMB session not RDP

Answer (score 7):

I need to modify your statement..  I had the same issue on a PC in my facility, and the **path** was:  "Security settings > **Local Policies** > Security Options > Microsoft Network Server: Amount of idle time required before suspending session".

I had to hunt for a bit, using your reference.  Though very good information, was not 100%.  This should correct it.

Comment: This is already set to 0 minutes for me and says "Do not disconnect clients:" Any other settings that could cause Remote Desktop to time out?

Comment: For this policy setting, a value of 0 means to disconnect an idle session as quickly as is reasonably possible. The maximum value is 99999, which is 208 days; in effect, this value disables the policy. Default:This policy is not defined, which means that the system treats it as 15 minutes for servers and undefined for workstations.

Comment: This answer is also about a setting that controls SMB sessions not RDP sessions.